# Setting up SSH keys for GitHub

Tags: ssh, github

I'm following [these instructions](http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/) for how to set up SSH keys for use with GitHub.

The instructions tell you to delete your current `.ssh` directory and create new keys in that .ssh directory. I'm unable to do this as I already have keys in my `id_dsa.pub` that I need to use for other servers.

Is it possible to set up SSH for GitHub while preserving the keys I already have saved in `.ssh`? Or is there another way to set up SSH for GitHub?

Answer (score 10):

You can either reuse  your key pair already in your directory, or create a new key-pair specifically for GitHub's use. If you decide not to use the default pair, you'll need to modify your `~/.ssh/config` file and add a host definition for GitHub pointing it to the new key file. So, if your new key pair is `github_rsa` and `github_rsa.pub`, put these lines in `/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa
```

Now, whenever you do pull or push operations to `git@github.com`, the alternate identity file will be used.

Answer (score 7):

You can generate keys with specific names like:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github -C "your_email@youremail.com"
```

And then you can specify this key for a separate server in the `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host *github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
  User git
```

See `man ssh` or `man ssh_config` for more details.

Comment: `User` needs to be set to `git` - I've made that change.

Comment: I dont find the config file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this in the global configuration:

```
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```