# Git: which key do I use (may not be by default)?

Tags: git, ssh, private-key, public-key

In my local environment (Mac OS X) I have at my home folder the .ssh folder, where there are two keys: github_rsa and id_rsa; in addition, there is a known_hosts file saying some like:

```
github.com,192.30.252.131 ssh-rsa blahblah
192.30.252.129 ssh-rsa blahlllblahhhh
...
```

Is there a way (command line preferred) for me to know which key my git command is using when interacting with Github or Bitbucket? If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id_rsa.pub` file contains the RSA public key for your user (generally the key used for connecting to GitHub, if you follow their [tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/)).  If you want to use the `github_rsa` key, you can change the key used to connect to GitHub by creating a new host definition in the `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa
```

By the way, the `known-hosts` file contains the servers you have connected to and their public keys.

See also this SO question: [Setting up ssh keys for GibHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455974/setting-up-ssh-keys-for-gibhub)

Answer (score 1):

The known-host file that you have given in the question has the public ssh-keys of the respective servers.

The private-public key pair are supposed to be for authentication!

Your .ssh folder is supposed to have two keys 1. Private key and 2. Public key. Public key has extension .pub and private key dosen't have any!

So most probably the two files that you have are one is Public (Which will also be there on github) and private.

Anyhow To know which key your github is using you can do this:

1. Find the public key in your github account and find its pair in your .ssh folder (i.e if you have maintained a proper nomenclature).
2. OR else Take your private key and run the command `ssh-keygen -y -f <private key file>`, it will create a public key. Compare the generated pub-key with your github!

Hope this explains a lot more than the question for your future use! :)

Comment: Cool! But is there a command line of git so it knows which key it is using currently? That should be more straightforward to check which key to use, and more convenient to write bash scripts for future.

Comment: Git has no direct relationship with SSH. Both are two different things!
When git tries to do any server operation it tries to do so on some remote! Based on which remote you are doing your operation you must have access rights to do so. This is where SSH comes into picture! To allow git(or you) to do cerain things! So, no there is no way to find via git command what you want!

Comment: Another answers is more to the point and I'll accept it. But great thanks for your help! I'll vote your answer up to reward you at least. ;-)